# numpy where returns an array. I need just index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array: `k = np.array([100,20,25,10,1,2])` and I'm trying to use a np where as `index=np.where(k<10)` which gives me 
`index (array([4, 5]),)`. I'm insterested in something to give me just the index so here I'd like to have `index[0]=4` not `index[0]=[4 5]`

I couldn't find anything here on the numpy docs.

Comment: There are two elements <10; therefore two indices.

Comment: I believe you can change `index = np.where(k<10)` to `index = np.where(k<10)[0]` to get what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you may be confused by the fact that `where` returns a tuple of arrays of indices, instead of just an array of indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the first element in the result that you get, as follows:

```
index=np.where(k<10)[0]
```

Then `index` is `array([4, 5], dtype=int64)`, and you can access `index[0]` and `index[1]` as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html), which returns an array of index instead of tuples of array(s):

```
k = np.array([100,20,25,10,1,2])

np.flatnonzero(k < 10)
# array([4, 5])
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing as what the OP did not want, and just uses a (relatively) obscure method to do so.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I am not so sure. This does give the same output as `numpy.where` but for 1d array, it has the convenience of returning an array of non zero elements index, instead of a tuple.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh works for me as I understand the OP's desire, but also completely non-obvious as a method to get those results.

Comment: @Psidom, the user clearly wants **an** element from the where tuple. This could either be `flatnonzero(cond)[0]`, or `where(cond)[0][0]`, or some other index.